# Index out of range error on Leetcode problem no 17

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

can anyone tell me why i am getting an **IndexError** in the following code. It doesn't make any sense to me.

```
class Solution(object):
    def letterCombinations(self, digits):
        matchnums={
        "2":["a","b","c"],
        "3":["d","e","f"],
        "4":["g","h","i"],
        "5":["j","k","l"],
        "6":["m","n","o"],
        "7":["p","q","r","s"],
        "8":["t","u","v"],
        "9":["w","x","y","z"]
        }
        res = []
        temp = matchnums[digits[0]]
        if digits=="":
            return res
        elif len(digits)==1:
            return matchnums[digits]
        else:
            for k in range(1,len(digits)):
                res=[]
                for i in range(len(temp)):
                    for j in range(len(matchnums[digits[k]])):
                        res.append(temp[i]+matchnums[digits[k]][j])
                temp=res
        return res
```

The error is in

```
temp = matchnums[digits[0]]
```

line. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is `digits`: string or list?

Comment: To get better answers to your question, you should also provide the code used to call your function. Especially to make it clear which value of `digits` leads to the `IndexError`.

Comment: It is a Leetcode problem so i don't have access to the calling function but when i tried to do it on my editor, the code ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Since digits could be an empty string, you need to check for that earlier.
Move

```
if digits=="":
    return res
```

before

```
temp = matchnums[digits[0]]
```